# building RStudio 1.1.414 64-bit still looking for libxslt.so.1

Tags: rstudio

I am trying to build RStudio on Centos7.  Specifically, the 64-bit version.  When I finish the build and try to load it, I am getting:

rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I had thought this was specific to building the 32-bit version on a 64-bit machine.  Anyone else seeing this?  Other suggestions?

This is the version I am downloading:
https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.1.414-x86_64-fedora.tar.gz

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Now thinking this is a dependency on epel which is NOT installed, so no libxslt anywhere.

Comment: yep, that was the issue, downloaded it, put it in the rstudio tar and then made a combined module